# How to address data from external url?

Tags: javascript, response, external

Now I have that code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29",
    data: {},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }  });
});
```

and get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I can see the right response from the url in my console and tried different dataTypes. What could be wrong?

Comment: show your ajax code and  only errors you got.

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted my code and error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. On my end this works.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                // an example of using result
        var myVar1 = result.lowest_price;
        var myVar2 = result.median_price;
        var myVar3 = result.success;
        var myVar4 = result.volume;

        alert(result.success);
            },
            error: function (result) {

            },
            fail: function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, my code was almost the same but i get this error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market…=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.my-domain.de' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

Comment: You seem to have your problem because of same-origin-policy (See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can call some AJAX method on your server, and in that method call that url, get data from it and return to the AJAX call.